# INotifyPropertyChanged when exposing raw Model instead of individual properties

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Here is the way I am implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` at the moment-

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Person Person1 { get; set; }
    public Person Person2 { get; set; }

    public string Person1Name
    {
        get { return Person1.Name; }
        set 
        { 
            Person1.Name = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Person1Name");
        }
    }

    public string Person2Name
    {
        get { return Person2.Name; }
        set 
        { 
            Person2.Name=value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Person2Name");
        }
    }
}

//This is the Model
public class Person
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And the XAML I am using for this type of implementation -

```
<Label Text="{Binding Path=Person1Name}"/>
<Label Text="{Binding Path=Person2Name}"/>
```

What I want to do is to IRaisePropertyChangedEvent whenever any property within the model changes, but I do not want to explicitly expose the property as I am doing there. I simply want to expose the whole model, and whenever a property within the model changes, it should raise notify event. But I do not want the model to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, I want ViewModel to implement it. So basically what I am looking is something like this -

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Person Person1
    {
        get { return _person1; }
        set
        {
            _person1 = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Person1"); 
            //So, whenever a property within my Person1 changes, raise event for that property.
        }
    }
    public Person Person2
    {
        get { return _person2; }
        set
        {
            _person2 = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Person2");
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Path=Person1.Name}"/>
<Label Text="{Binding Path=Person2.Name}"/>
```

How would I do this? If think question is unclear, please comment and I will try better.

Comment: This is why I dislike this construction. While at first this seems a quick way to build a viewmodel, in the end it will prove to be dirty as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, unless `Person` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you have no way to track when a property within the person instance is changed.

A binding like this:

```
 <Label Text="{Binding Path=Person1.Name}"/>
```

Does not change the `Person1` *instance*, but rather a property within the same instance.  Unless that class implements INPC, you'll never "see" that the property has changed, and never raise your event.

Comment: i know i could make the model implement inpc, but I thought Model should not know anything about the view, and only ViewModel should be updating the view.

Comment: INPC does not couple your model to the ViewModel or View. It is the convention to signal when something has changed.

Comment: @AnkurSharma I (personally) don't have a problem with a model implementing INPC -but if you want to avoid it, you'll need to wrap the Model within its own VM to get that interface implemented.  One of the main reasons a VM exists is to implement INPC...

Comment: @ReedCopsey I agree. My MVVM models are usually separate from my domain/data models.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your Person object in a ViewModel also:

```
public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private Person _person;

   public PersonViewModel(Person person)
   {
       _person = person;
   }

   public string Name
   {
       get 
       {
           return _person.Name;
       }
       set
       {
          _person.Name = value;
          RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
       }
    }
}
```

then your viewmodel class will look like:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public PersonViewModel Person1
    {
        get { return _person1; }
        set
        {
            _person1 = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Person1"); 
            //So, whenever a property within my Person1 changes, raise event for that property.
        }
    }
    public PersonViewModel Person2
    {
        get { return _person2; }
        set
        {
            _person2 = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Person2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I consider this more of an ActionModel than a ViewModel since it's only purpose is to relay changes to the Domain Model.

Comment: @Romoku: Am not familiar with the difference between ViewModel and ActionModel. Where can I find more info?

Comment: I'll dig it out of my bookmarks when I get home. In a nutshell the difference is superficial since ViewModels are tied to one View while ActionModels are generic and can be used across many ViewModels/Views. The concept also manifests in MVC when your Page can have multiple Actions happening while not sharing the same ViewModel.